# Trim the path upto a certain string using batch command

Tags: batch-file

I have path in a variable from registry that looks like this :

```
SET dirpath="D:\Veritas\product\7.5.0.2\bin\DBBACKEX.EXE BACKUPDIR"
```

I need output only upto bin folder using windows batch command that should look this: `D:\Veritas\product\7.5.0.2\bin`

I used a simple VBScript within the batch command like in below code which did the job, but i need it using batch command only without the use of another file.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%p in (`CSCRIPT //nologo regpath.vbs %dirPath%`) DO SET VPath=%%p
```

I don't see much string manipulation functions in batch commands, I want to remove the CSCRIPT line in above code and use only batch command. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *"trim the path upto a certain string"* using the string "bin" as you requested, you may use this simple method:

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET "dirpath=D:\Veritas\product\7.5.0.2\bin\DBBACKEX.EXE BACKUPDIR"

SET "VPath=%dirpath:bin=bin" & rem "%"

echo %VPath%
```

The trick consist in split the path at the desired string and eliminate the rest via a `rem` command; you may remove the `@echo off` line and execute the code in order to see what exactly is executed...

Comment: Super @Aacini. Works as expected ! Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

use `for` modifiers to get the drive/path:

```
for %%a in ("%dirpath%") do set dirpath=%%~dpa
```

See `for /?` for a description of the modifiers.